# Properly Sorting Fractional Data in SQL Select

Tags: php, mysql, sql-order-by

My database column is a `varchar(25)` datatype with values 1 1/2", 1/2", 3", and 4" representing hose diameters for a fire station. The issue I am having is that the following code spits out the hose diameters in the above order in the database when I want to order in ascending order, meaning I want "1/2, 1 1/2, 3, 4" not with the 1 1/2 at the front. IS there a way to do this in SQL with fractional data values for my `varchar` datatype?

```
// Select hose locations from fire database
$query = "SELECT hose_diameter FROM hose_diameter ORDER BY hose_diameter";
$result = $mysqli->query($query) or die($mysqli->error.__LINE__);

//FETCH ROWS
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print "<option value=\"".$row['hose_diameter']."\">".$row['hose_diameter']."</option>";
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd modify your database so that you have an actual decimal value in there, which you could then sort by properly. You could have both as regular columns, or one computed based on the other, or just have the decimal one and let the app translate that to readable values. Or you could have a translation table which you join against (like Gordon's subquery idea, but with a real table) would also work assuming your possible values are fixed. But I would avoid having just a mixed-number string in the database if you want to treat it like a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way.  It just gets rid of the "1/2" for the first sort and then adds it back in:

```
order by replace(diam, '1/2', ''), diam
```

Of course, this doesn't generalize easily to other fractions very easily.

Another way is to add a `'0'` to the front when it starts with one character before the `'/'`:

```
order by (case when diam like '_/%' then '0'+diam else diam end)
```

Finally, you could have a lookup table for the diameter as a number:

```
SELECT hd.hose_diameter
FROM hose_diameter hd left outer join
     (select '1/2' as hose_diameter, 0.5 as units union all
      select '1 1/2', 1.5 union all
      select '3', 3 union all
      select '4', 4
     )diams
     on hd.hose_diameter = diams.hose_diameter
ORDER BY diams.units;
```

I actually prefer this method, because the intention is clear.

EDIT:

I don't understand the comment.  I just tested this code:

```
with hose_diameter as (
      select '1/2' as diam union all
      select '1 1/2' union all
      select '3'
     )
SELECT hd.diam
FROM hose_diameter hd left outer join
     (select '1/2' as hose_diameter, 0.5 as units union all
      select '1 1/2', 1.5 union all
      select '3', 3 union all
      select '4', 4
     ) diams
     on hd.diam = diams.hose_diameter
ORDER BY diams.units;
```

And it returns:

```
1/2
1 1/2
3
```

I tested the first version, and it returns the same ordering.  And the second version too.

Comment: Thanks, but when I implemented your code it just yields same result.